# Can Djinn be captured by human?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, jinn

Assalamualaikum and greeting from Malaysia.

I would like to ask if Djinn can be captured by human? I would love to know it since, I have a family members that been disturb by a Djinn, we try to treat him with Islamic method and some of the method are by capturing the Djinn (but before that they will recite a Du'a from Quran which is correct base on my understanding) and they proceed by putting the Djinn in the bottle, and the bottle need to be throw into the sea or river.

Is this thing is possible in Islam? since according to history, even Prophet Muhammad doesn't catch a Djinn and put him in a bottle. I heard a story that Prophet Muhammad catching an Ifrit that try to disturb Prophet's solah, but after that, the prophet just release him.

Thus, how come the Djinn can be captured by normal human?

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Djin means a hidden creature. I am also a Djin for you at this time in one sense as i am hidden from you right now. So can you capture me ? Yes i guess. Just a proper planning is required to capture me. This world is so mysterious. Full of mysteries and many things are hidden from human eyes. Through proper planning you can have control on such things but i am not sure what proper planning is required for that.

Further i would like to tell two scientific theories that will shed some light on this issue.

1.There are some factors around us like infra sound and electromagnetic field  that may cause visual disturbance and you may see the things that actually do not exist.

2.There are some physical exercises to make you physically strong as you know  same like that there are also some mental exercises designed to make your mind strong. If you will do those mental exercises then probably you can do something that is unusual. Many Muslim Sufis, Jewish Rabbis, Christian priests, Hindu Pandits are Buddist monks are good at it. It certainly does not determine how much close someone is to God as anyone can get a proper training to get that.

Other than that i can not tell you further about Djins because of lack of knowledge.

Comment: I suggest you to look here:[How do I write a good answer?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

jinn can be captured, but to capture the jinn in bottle is just fiction. First of all one should not try to captured jinn if they didn't disturb him. If one try to capture them without any precautions and correct method of capturing, the jinn may get anger and destroy one's life. It is good to stay away from them. if jinn disturb you just recite three time "ayat-ul-kursi" and blow on your hands and rub  over your whole body.

Comment: Welcome to islam se. Please read http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer to evaluate your answer